# Is "With the Wish of Wellness" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, syntactic-analysis

Recently one of my friends who is not a native English speaker sent me a mail. In the last phrase he used a harmonic but strange structure instead of the usual phrases like "Best Regards", "Best Wishes", "Sincerely", etc.

That phrase was: "With the Wish of Wellness".

Question: Is this a legitimate English phrase? If not, which grammatical rules does it violate?

Comment: It's not one I've seen before but it certainly grabs my attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's valid as a valediction.

It leaves out the subject and verb, but then so does "best regards", etc.

From context we know all valedictions to include something along the lines of "I send this to you..." or "I ask you..." and possibly also a joining "with". Hence "I send this to you with best regards", or "I send this to you with the wish of wellness".

It's an unusual valediction, but perfectly grammatical.

(Note, my wording of "I send this to you..." is an approximation of the general meaning, one might phrase the connection between message and valediction in several other ways).

Comment: The usual nearby expression is 'Wishing you well'. Your friend may have been aiming for this, or may have been trying to convey sincerity by tweaking what is certainly a cliché.